# Creating the `formality` tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

How about making this tag? Currently all my questions about the formality is tagged under the `tone` tag. But I think we should make a `formality` tag separately.

What do you think?

Comment: We generally aim for tags to be nouns, so "formal" isn't a good name.  Formal-writing? Formality?  Could you edit into your question a bit more about what you'd like this tag to mean -- maybe a candidate tag-wiki excerpt?

Comment: just about everything that relate to formality?

Comment: Agreed, I'd like to know more about what this tag would be. "Formal writing" or a similar tag would probably be applied to a lot of tech and academic writing, and I'm not sure that's the point here. Looking at [Ooker's questions](http://writers.stackexchange.com/users/11428/ooker?tab=questions), could it be that we just need to apply the [tag:essay] tag more consistently?

Comment: @NeilFein do you think that `formal writing` tag can be a synonym of the `essay` tag?

Comment: No, I think that essay writing can be formal but doesn't have to be. I'd like to see what others say, though.

Comment: @Ooker we still need a better idea of what you mean by "formal".  Saying the tag would be fore "anything that relates to formality" is circular.  If you can't describe it, there's no hope that others  can evaluate it (or correctly apply it, if it's created).

Comment: I agree with Neil Fein that `essay` is not completely a synonym with `formal writing`. @MonicaCellio, circular? That's just exactly what I mean